# Convert type Task<IEnumerable> to type IEnumerable

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have the following expression which is of the type `Task<IEnumerable<PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest>>` and I need to convert it to `IEnumerable<PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest>`. How do I do that ?

```cs
Task<IEnumerable<PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest>> pendingChangeRequest = service.GetPendingChangeRequest();
```

Comment: `await pendingChangeRequest`. You're in for a world of pain if the parent function isn't `async`.

Comment: You could also theoretically access the result, by appending a continuiation Task. But that is 1) A pain to deal with and 2) This operation was propably made Asynchronous because it could take a long time. | So just using "await in a async method" is easier. That deals with setting the rest of that function as continuation, without you having to deal with all that plumbing work. I only mentioned it for completness sake.

Answer (score 5):

You can `await` it in an `async` method:

```cs
IEnumerable<PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest> result = await pendingChangeRequest;
```

You can read more about asynchronous programming [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

You should also read these [best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming) from MSDN if you have to introduce `async` in your codebase (which seems to be your case).

Answer (score 0):

You have two paths:

1. Use `await` before calling.
   In this case it will work asynchronously.
2. Invoke `.Result` after calling. There your code will stop here and synchronously wait the result of the `Task` working.

Comment: The second path should only be used [in last resort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming) of course.